# Android Emulator - How to send a http post request to it?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, nanohttpd

I created an app that uses nanohttpd to set up a small http listener. To test this i need to be able to send post request to the webserver on the emulator from my host machine using postman.

So that i would be able to send a post request to http://:1234/, which the app will then interpret. The app is working fine on my tablet, but for testing porpuses i need to find a way to do this on emulators as that would make my testing more flexible

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Have you checked the "Android Emulator networking" settings? https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Comment: You better test the nanohttp server using a browser on the emulator or an app on the emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a redirect port from your host machine to your app's listening port. For instance if your app is listening on port 8080, then you can use set the redir as follows:

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

Then once you are authorized, enter

```
redir add tcp:8080:8080
```

Now any request sent on your local machine's localhost:8080 will be sent your emulator's localhost:8080. Now you can use Postman to send a request on localhost:8080 on your local machine.